# xcode: resolve merge conflicts failed

Tags: xcode, git

I try to merge two branches with Xcode. I get conflict, and I use "let then right" button to reconcile conflict. But when I click "merge", Xcode shows the error

```
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge.
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The four icons at the bottom mean this:

1. **left then right** - keep both changes, placing the left code before the right
2. **left** - keep only the left file
3. **right** - keep only the right file
4. **right then left** - keep both changes, placing the right code before the left

You chose "left then right" as you stated. However, I see that in your code both files have `<outlet property="bottomView">` and `<outlet property="finishSuiDuButton">` line which will result in duplicate code after merge, since the code from **both** files will be included. It looks to me like the option you actually want is option 2 - keep only the left file.

Either that or remove the duplicate code from one of the files and you should be good. :)